# Как вывести на экран нужный ключ с сайта?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, парсер

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
url = "https://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=5&country=us&appid=730&market_hash_name=Recoil%20Case&format=json"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(r.text,'lxml')
print(soup)
```

На экран выводится:

```
<html><body><p>{"success":true,"lowest_price":"18,40 pуб.","volume":"79,670","median_price":"80,11 pуб."}</p></body></html>
```

Вопрос: как мне вывести только цену? К примеру, 80,11 pуб.

Comment: Если это json, то зачем здесь вообще beautifulsoup? Просто `r.json()["median_price"]` да и всё

Comment: andreymal, Я просто только учусь :D Спасибо огромное за помощь <3